# Using Flutter Launch default browser with intent and post parameters

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Using Flutter try to open browser with post parameter.

Example : http://www.stackoverflow.com?par1=val1&par2=val2

But I don't want to send the parameters with get but with post. How can I do this as described above?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can launch default browser with **POST**. Browser only send **GET** request of a URL.

I guess your purpose of using **POST** instead of **GET** may be for security reason.  So in order to achieve this, you need an API endpoint which accept POST with those parameters, then that endpoint will return a token, then you can use this token to authenticate the request or retrieve the parameters from the session.