# open url as post request in flutter

Tags: flutter, post

How to open the url in browser with post request with parameters not get?

I don't want that id and token parameters shows in the url field in the browser.

The following code using "url_launcher" package open the url like this in the browser, and that is not what I need:
https://example.com/api/show_content?id=271281&token=DSAGH54345FDAFHHGHTsas

```
   var uri =   Uri(scheme: 'https', host: example.com, path: 'api/show_content', queryParameters: {
      'id': 85,
      'token': user_token,
    });

  await launchUrl(uri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
```

Comment: When you launch an url in the browser it will always perform a get request https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56465148/using-flutter-launch-default-browser-with-intent-and-post-parameters

Answer (score 0):

you should pass in your token and id as params, that way it should not be visible in the browser.

this should help

```
void openURL() async {
  final String baseUrl = 'https://example.com';
  final String id = '123';
  final String token = 'abc';

  final String url = '$baseUrl/path?id=$id&token=$token';

  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Comment: He stated that the parameters shouldnt show in the url field. Wouldnt this be the case with your solution?