Open external browser from flutter app with post method
From my Flutter app, I want to submit POST request with post data to an external web browser to open payement view
I tried url_launcher library but it doesn't support post data so it is not enough
My post data is formatted as JSON

how about use webview instead open external browser. https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter

For this only in_app_webview is the only options. This might help you to get clarification. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58742063/13973724

can you add your code snipet?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
